# How To dynamically Add row To Google Chart with for loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bar-chart

I Have Problem in Google chart.

I am using asp.net Mvc. After I fetch data from controller, I pass it into Google chart .

When i use manual data, for example:

```
['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
```

It Show me correctly .

But how can i add my data dynamically into Google chart ?

This is my code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Element', 'Density', {role: 'style'}],
        [chartsdata[i].MonthValue, chartsdata[i].CountValue, '#b87333']
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: ''
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: How did you assign chartsdata?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are doing is wrong.You should do something like below:

```
 var data=[];
 var Header= ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }];
 data.push(Header);
 for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {
      var temp=[];
      temp.push(chartsdata[i].MonthValue);
      temp.push(chartsdata[i].CountValue);

      data.push(temp);
  }
var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use "`google.visualization.DataTable()`" and its "`addRow()`"  [Google code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
data.addColumn('number', 'Count');

for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {
     data.addRow([chartsdata[i].month, chartsdata[i].count]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me:

```
var data=[];

var Header= ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }];

data.push(Header);

for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {

      var temp=[];
      temp.push(chartsdata[i].MonthValue);
      temp.push(chartsdata[i].CountValue);
      temp.push("red"); //this will change based on value of 'i' variable
      data.push(temp);
  }

var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```